# Separate tables for openid logins

Tags: sql-server, facebook, openid, google-authentication

My website has a normal sign up and sign in process now I want to add google login (and later facebook, yahoo and ...) to my website but I'm not quiet sure how to change my user table.

1. Add all user info I get from google, facebook as new fields to my current users table? each login type gives me a first and a last name I just can keep one of them. the only user info to connect different login types with each other is the email address. So if a user has used different email for his/her facebook account than his gmail then each user will have lots of unused fields.
2. Using separate tables for each login types. have a google table, facebook table and ... and connect each record with a user in user table (if user has not signed up before google or facebook information will e used to create one). in this case user record will have a missing password field that of course can be resetted from account or by password forgotton function

which one is the correct way to do this?